# node server, Redux doesn't dispatch content back to UI component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

The issue is when I do npm run start-dev to run client side code, it works perfectly. But whenever I run npm run start to start up the server side. The Client side doesn't dispatch the content back to UI. Need help.

Server.js

```
'use strict';

import path from 'path';
import { Server } from 'http';
import Express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import NotFoundPage from './components/NotFoundPage';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
const content = require('./Action/reducer');

// initialize the server and configure support for ejs templates
const app = new Express();
const server = new Server(app);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// define the folder that will be used for static assets
app.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

// universal routing and rendering
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  match(
    { routes, location: req.url },
    (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
      const store = createStore(content);

      // in case of error display the error message
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
      }

      // in case of redirect propagate the redirect to the browser
      if (redirectLocation) {
        return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
      }

      // generate the React markup for the current route
      let markup;
      if (renderProps) {
        // if the current route matched we have renderProps
        markup = renderToString(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <RouterContext {...renderProps}/>
          </Provider>
        );
      } else {
        // otherwise we can render a 404 page
        markup = renderToString(<NotFoundPage/>);
        res.status(404);
      }
      res.send(renderFullPage(markup))

      // render the index template with the embedded React markup
      // return res.render('index', { markup });
    }
  );
});

function renderFullPage(html) {
  return `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="assets/img/apple-icon.png">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
      <title>Chris</title>

      <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

      <link href="bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link href="assets/css/gsdk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link href="assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <!--     Font Awesome     -->
      <link href="bootstrap3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Grand+Hotel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="main">${html}</div>
      <script src="../static/js/bundle.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script src="bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/gsdk-checkbox.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/gsdk-radio.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/gsdk-bootstrapswitch.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/get-shit-done.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>

    `
  }


// start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
server.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.info(`Server running on http://localhost:${port} [${env}]`);
});
```

Client:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import Layout from './components/Layout';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
const reducer = require('./Action/reducer');
const store = createStore(reducer);

// import { createStore } from 'redux';
// const content = require('./Action/reducer');
// const store = createStore(content);
// import Layout from './components/Layout';
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('main')
)
```

Layout.js

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

// const actions = require('../Action/actions');
import * as actions from '../Action/actions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Layout extends React.Component {
  handleSwitchLang(targetLang) {
    this.props.switchLanguage(targetLang);
  }

  render() {
    let switchLanguage = this.props.switchLanguage;
    let content = this.props.content;
    return (
      some UI code
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { content: state.content }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Layout);
```

reducer.js

```
const action_types = require('./action_types');
import json from '../../lang.json';


const initialState = {
  content: json.en // Loads default language content (en) as an initial state
};

const reducer = function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case action_types.SWITCH_LANGUAGE:
      return {
        content: json[action.language]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

module.exports = reducer;
```

You can try out my code if you want. Here is my github project.
https://github.com/luznlun/samwebsite
clone the project. do npm install, npm runs start-dev to run client side(Working), npm run start(problem with dispatch).

Really appreciate the help

Comment: what exactly is the "problem with dispatch"?  is there error information in your browser console or in your terminal?

Comment: so I Click on the button in Layout component, which will call switchLanguage(). it will change the state of content. At that point, data suppose to get dispatched, and update the UI component with the updated content in this.props.